# HAML if else with table row

Tags: ruby, haml

I have the following code:

```
  - if 0
    %tr{:style => "background-color: red"}
  - else
    %tr
      %td.main= database_manager.db_old_name
      %td= database_manager.db_type
      %td= database_manager.server
      %td= database_manager.instance
      %td= database_manager.host
      %td= database_manager.port
      %td= database_manager.last_read.localtime.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
      %td= database_manager.updated_at.localtime.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
```

which does not work. My intentions is to highlight the row if condition is 1 and not if 0.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use and compare a variable in your haml file / view which is defined in the controller.

```
- if @yourvariable == 0
    %tr{:style => "background-color: red"}
- else
  ...
```